# Flat mapping a future with "rollback" code

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

I'm having trouble finding an elegant solution to chaining some futures. The method I'm trying to implement looks like this (it's part of a cache):

```
def acquire(key: A, producer: => Future[B]): Future[B]
```

And the algorithm is approximately this:

- if the key is locked, through a runtime exception immediately (would there be an advance of using Future.failed?)
- otherwise open a `future { getOrRefresh }` block because it needs some time to retrieve the key
- `getOrRefresh` either returns a straight `B` which is then the result of the future and method
- or it needs to run the `producer`

The last step implies that I need a 'flattening' of the future from *inside the future*. That is, I cannot do a `outer.flatMap`, so I guess the strategy is to use `Await`.

Now, `Await` has a strange schizophrenia in that you can either get an `Option[Try[B]]`, using method `ready`, or the unwound `B`, using `result`. The problem is, I need to release a lock in the case of `Failure` before completing the outer future, so I have to stick to `Await.ready`, I guess.

This gets ugly:

```
val fut   = producer
val prod  = Await.ready(fut, Duration.Inf).value.get
if (prod.isFailure) sync.synchronized { locked = false }
prod.get
```

Can this be that ugly? There must be a better way to do this.

---

So to repeat: From within a `Future[B]` run some peer future that also completes with `B`, and return the peer's result, but in the case of failure, clean up a lock before completing the main future.

Answer (score 0):

Here an attempt using `recover(With)` and thereby avoiding `Await`. Still, it looks clunky, because I need to rethrow the exception

```
import concurrent._

trait Cache[A, B] {
  class Entry(var locked: Boolean = true)

  private var map  = Map.empty[A, Entry]
  private val sync = new AnyRef

  implicit def exec: ExecutionContext

  def readEntry(key: A): Option[B]

  def acquire(key: A, producer: => Future[B]): Future[B] = sync.synchronized {
    map.get(key) match {
      case Some(e) =>
        if (e.locked) throw new IllegalStateException()
        e.locked     = true
        val existing = future { readEntry(key).get }
        val refresh  = existing.recoverWith {
          case _: NoSuchElementException => producer
        }
        refresh.recover {
          case t => sync.synchronized(e.locked = false); throw t
        }

      case _ => producer.map { value =>
        sync.synchronized {
          map += key -> new Entry()
        }
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you have suggestions, please post them as a separate answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what acquire really does. Since locking is tied to the Entry and it is never returned how does it ever get unlocked? Is there a release() method that's omitted?

Comment: @ArneClaassen -  yes, sorry, there is a `release` method; it's not depicted because it doesn't directly relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of changes to your implementation.

First, i've turned your initial `throw` on locked into a `Future.failed`,  since consumers of futures should be safe to assume that the only failure to watch for is a failed future.

Next, rather than calling `get` on the `Option[B]` from `readEntry`, I'm returning it as the result of the future. Then I `flatMap` the result so that I can substitute the future produced by `producer` in the case of `None` (map would result in a Future[Future[B]]). In the case of `Some`, I return a `Future.successful` from the value, since the `flatMap` requires a future to be returned.

Finally, I've replaced the `recover` and `throw` with an `andThen` because we want the failed `Future` to propagate and only want to chain a side-effect to the future to unlock the entry.

```
trait Cache[A, B] {
  class Entry(var locked: Boolean = true)

  private var map  = Map.empty[A, Entry]
  private val sync = new AnyRef

  def readEntry(key: A): Option[B] = ???

  def acquire(key: A, producer: => Future[B]): Future[B] = sync.synchronized {
    map.get(key) match {
      case Some(e) =>
        if (e.locked)
          Future.failed(new IllegalStateException())
        else {
        e.locked = true
        future { readEntry(key)}.flatMap {
          case None => producer.andThen {
            case Failure(_) => sync.synchronized(e.locked = false)
          }
          case Some(value) => Future.successful(value)
        }
      }

      case _ => producer.map { value =>
        sync.synchronized {
          map += key -> new Entry()
        }
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```